# Magento 2 - Get the postcode entered in the Estimate Shipping block

Tags: magento2, shipping

I'm trying to get the postcode that has been entered in the Estimate Shipping block on the basket page. I am trying to grab it from local storage.
I have the following code on a template file that is called on the homepage:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery','Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'], function($,quote){
        console.log(quote.shippingAddress().postcode)
    })
</script>
```

This one returns an error in the console: `quote.shippingAddress(...) is null`

I have also tried to retrieve it via the cart session:

```
...
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
...

public function __construct(
    Cart $cart,) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

public function getCustomerDeliveryPostcode() {
    $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $postcode = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
}
```

This one returns nothing.
Can anyone see what is wrong?
Magento 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
protected $cartSess;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $cartSess
)
{
   $this->cartSess=$cartSess;
}

public function getPostcode()
{
    $quote =$this->cartSess->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
       $postcode = $address->getPostCode();
    }

    return $postcode;

}
```

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. The full address information has not been entered in the Estimate Shipping block which is probably why this method doesn't work.